# Clearing Chrome to make Google Tag Assistant reload?

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have the following situation:

When I use Google Tag Assistant to check the trackings for my website, it shows 2 trackings. This must come from some cache because when I try it on another computer with a freshly installed Chrome, it shows 1 tracking (which should be correct).

Does anybody know what I could do to fully refresh Chrome to make GTA use the current website version?

I can't use an incognito window because GTA doesn't work with incognito windows, I think.

Clearing all caches (with all clearing options set) did not change anything.

Comment: It also can be comming from another chrome extension. I use a few Chrome extensions that load their own GA tracking and it does show up in GTA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to navigate to tag assistant extension settings and allow it on incognito window. So it will show up in incognito window